# perl: one parent, many children - single pipe reader in parent?

Tags: perl

is it possible in perl to establish a pipe in such a way that the parent has only one READER pipe and many children write to it as they come to life/exit?

The typical cookbook code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# pipe2 - use pipe and fork so child can send to parent

use IO::Handle;
pipe(READER, WRITER);
WRITER->autoflush(1);

if ($pid = fork) {
    close WRITER;
    chomp($line = <READER>);
    print "Parent Pid $$ just read this: `$line'\n";
   // do what you need
} else {
    die "cannot fork: $!" unless defined $pid;
    close READER;
    print WRITER "Child Pid $$ is sending this\n";
    close WRITER;  # this will happen anyway
    exit;
}
```

Let's instead assume a case where I need my parent "READER" to get messages from multiple children, is it possible to do this without keeping a list of pipes, one per child? I can't close WRITER in the parent because the next child won't get a valid handle to write to. I also need the parent to continue its regular operation and not block on any client data from the pipe.

Pseudocode of what I need:

```
# parent code
pipe (READER, WRITER)
fork_random_number_of_children(READER,WRITER)

on_some_tick => {
    my $data = read_from(READER, non_blocking)
    if (data) print "Hey some child sent me: $data"
    else print "No data, going back life"
    do_other_things_before_next_tick()
}

child_job(R,W) { # lets assume this is called for each child fork
  close (R); # no problem, its a copy
  sleep (random duration)
  print W, "Message from child with pid $$"
  exit 0
}
```

Comment: Can this be well served by a simple server? (Specially with those callbacks.) It seems to me that this pope joggling may be pushing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to `close WRITER` in the parent. It may be a good practice, but since you can't reuse the same pipe for new child processes after you close it, that's a good excuse not to do it. If you keep `WRITER` open until you are done launching all your child processes, you can reuse the pipe with multiple child processes. Here's a proof of concept:

```
use IO::Handle;
use POSIX ':sys_wait_h';
pipe(READER,WRITER);
WRITER->autoflush(1);

sub child_process {
    my $stage = shift;
    close READER;  # also a best but optional practice
    srand($$);
    do {
        sleep 1 + 5*rand();
        print WRITER "Child Pid $$ ($stage) is sending this\n";
    } while (rand > 0.5);
    exit;
}

# initial set of children
for (my $i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        child_process("LAUNCH");
    }
}

# parent
my ($rin,$rout) = ('');
vec($rin,fileno(READER),1) = 1;
while (1) {
     # non-blocking read on pipe
     my $read_avail = select($rout=$rin, undef, undef, 0.0);
     if ($read_avail < 0) {
         if (!$!{EINTR}) {
             warn "READ ERROR: $read_avail $!\n";
             last;
         }
     } elsif ($read_avail > 0) {
         chomp(my $line = <READER>);
         print "Read in Parent $$: '$line'\n";
     } else {
         print STDERR "No input ... do other stuff\n";
         # start some run-time child processes
         if (time-$^T > 5 && time-$^T < 10) {
             # launch a few more children in the middle of the program
             if (fork() == 0) {
                 child_process("RUN");
             }
         }
         sleep 1;
     }
     last if waitpid(-1,&WNOHANG) < 0;    # no more children are alive
}
close WRITER;  # now it is safe to do this ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Doing more testing - seems to work the way I want!. You said this is a proof of concept. Any key issues that I need to investigate that you've left as an exercise?

Comment: As a start, you should check the return value of syscalls like [pipe](https://perldoc.pl/functions/pipe) and whether [fork](https://perldoc.pl/functions/fork) returns undef to indicate failure.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use lexical filehandles instead of global barewords, to prevent clashing with code elsewhere, it also means they'll close automatically when they go out of scope which can be easier to manage. `pipe(my $reader, my $writer) or die "pipe failed: $!";` You should also be using `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: You can also use an event loop like [Mojo::IOLoop](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop) or [IO::Async](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async) which are designed to do exactly this sort of thing (either at a similar low level, or managing everything itself) rather than managing a select loop and waitpid yourself. I can come up with an example if you're interested.

Comment: @mob A couple of questions/concerns: from what I see the write-end in all kids is the exact same resource -- aren't there going to be conflicts when they write around the same time (overlapping data read by the parent)?  (Also, this parent doesn't write so can it not close its write end right away?)

Comment: Thank you @Grinnz - yes, I've put my checks around those critical calls. With respect to your kind offer on the other event loops - this current code seems to meet my needs well so far, so I'll stick with it for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Second-order issues: synchronization of write operations, reading too slowly from the pipe so the pipe fills and writers are blocked, checking return values of all function calls for errors.  @zdim - you can't close the write end in the parent until you are sure that you are not going to spawn any more children that will use the write end.

Comment: @user1361529 A comment on the "proof of concept" -- I'd take that phrase to be intended to remind to work through this to ensure that there are no race conditions, all synchronization and buffering etc is taken care of, no resource is left hanging, etc.

Comment: @zdim, It would really suck if the data from two children would be intermixed, but I think POSIX makes certain guarantees about this (like the writes being atomic if under a certain size), but I'm not sure what those guarantees are if they exist.

Comment: I can only offer anecdotal evidence - I am using @mobs code in an alarm notification server with 8 cameras pumping alarms as people walk by. Lots of overlapping forks as each child invokes neural net models that take time for image classification. So far his code is working like Bruce Lee's kung-fu.

Comment: @user1361529 Great, and that's an interesting application.  The fact that each child does considerable work helps, since I'd expect any mixing (if possible) to relate to a race condition. And there's far less chance for that if jobs take a while.

Comment: @mob so related problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072736/perl-non-blocking-pipe-only-getting-one-message